# Incorrect display of values from the Look up SharePoint column field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sharepoint

Everything hi, I use search of sharepoint the list, I see information in case of a choice, but I can't understand to copy field value, look for in other, I instead of values quit an ID (1, 2, 3, 4...), it is necessary that in the field of "Title", it was copied in case of a choice information from the "Select" field why so occurs? I.e. if selected User from the list, User in the field shall be shown.

here code:

```
   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(LoadSLNCascade, "SP.js");

    function LoadSLNCascade() {

        $('#countries').SLN_SPcascadingdropdown(
        {
            relationshipList: "List",
            relationshipParentList: "List",
            relationshipParentListColumn: "First",
            relationshipListChildColumn: "First",
            relationshipListParentColumn: "Seccond",
            childDropDown: "cities",
            autoFillParentDropDownList: true,
            defaulFillChildDropDownList: false,
            promptText: "-- Select Value --"
        }); 
}

$('#countries').change(function() {
$('#TitleField').val($(this).val());
```

});

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#list").change(function() {
    $("#field").val($('option:selected', this).text());
  });
});
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#list").change(function() {
    $("#field").val($('option:selected', this).text());
  });
});
```